# How to change my font in same line on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, fonts

I want to change my font (amion) with Nexa font and other letters with Roboto, how do I change that using Flutter?
[font_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxJZC.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `RichText` widget, that allows to apply `textStyle` to the text spans. A sample below:

```
body: Center(
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: 'Say Hello to ', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto', color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(text: 'Amion', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Nexa', color: Colors.black, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                  TextSpan(text: ' app !', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto', color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))
                ]
              ),

            ),
          )
```

You just need to replace the `fontFamily` with whatever you need. I just gave `Roboto` and `Nexa` as an example for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

just do it in a Row, you can change the style of the Text as you want, including the font

```
new Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Text(
      "bla",
      style: new TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
    new Text(
      "bla",
      style: new TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: good for couple of words but not a great Idea if you have a long paragraph or line,Rich Text should help as mentioned by @Darshan